# How to remove the '~' files forever?

Tags: git

Everytime I checkout a branch this is what happens:

```
M   src/note/views.py~
D   src/static/assets/css/inside.css~
D   src/templates/index.html~
D   src/templates/note/create.html~
D   src/templates/note/list.html~
D   src/templates/note/unite.html~
```

Which is quite irritating and makes me sick. How do I remove these files forever?

Comment: If you're in git bash its rm -rf src/note/views.py~ and etc

Comment: this looks like `svn st`... so there is more to this question than just git?

Comment: @ChrisMaes FWIW you can create this output with `git status --porcelain`. Not sure if that's the case here of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to ignore them (these are backup files written by your editor). Have a `.gitignore` file.

Actually `.gitignore` is the first file I am adding to a fresh new `git` repo

So, edit `.gitignore` to contain at least `*~` on a line (and perhaps another line with `*.o` if you have object files, etc). Then

```
git add .gitignore
```

You might also remove these files, e.g. with `rm -vi **/*~` or `rm -vi *~ */*~` (or use `find`) - perhaps also, as [Chris Maes answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817614/841108), using `git rm`

Comment: Ignoring them won't do any good since .gitignore only applies to untracked files and these files clearly already are tracked. The correct solution is to delete the files with `git rm`.

Comment: I had to use "rm -f" to remove the files. And then I added '*~' to .gitignore. Seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

They probably shouldn't be versioned at all. Use `git rm` to remove them:

```
git rm src/note/views.py~
```

If you just don't want them to appear in git status, add them to `.gitignore` as @basile suggests

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to remove `~` files and avoid this happening from again,

1. .gitignore only works with untracked files, so it won't help with existing `~` files.
   But you should add the following lines in `.gitignore` file to avoid this from happening again.

   ```
   *~
   *.swp
   ```
2. now delete all `~` files from your project with this command,

   ```
   find . -name "*~" -print | xargs rm
   ```
3. and then remove the files which were already added in your git repository,

   ```
   git rm $(git ls-files --deleted)
   ```

and then commit your changes.