# Is it bad to commit all files always on git?

Tags: git

i.e git commit -am?

I am not aware of any repercusions this could have later on a merge for example.

Comment: If you have config `.gitignore` properly, then I think it's ok and should always use in this way. If you need to commit only part of changes, then probably it's time for you to create more branches to separate changes into branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git commit -a` does not commit all files. Instead, it only commits all files which are already under version control and have unstaged changes (in addition to files already staged).

> ```
>    -a, --all
>       Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been
>       modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are
>       not affected.
> ```

This is different from `git add -A`, which adds all files and to which other answers refer. That will add all untracked and not ignored (see [gitignore](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)).

Using `git commit -a` is not harmful per-se. There are two issues which can arise:

1. Your commits may become large, which is hindering when searching for the cause of a regression (see [git bisect](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html)). To avoid this, you should look into `git commit -p`.
2. You may miss files which are untracked (this can only be avoided by using `git status`, `git add` and your brain).

As for merges, git performs merges based on the individual changes in a file. Thus, it does not matter how many files are in one commit. But making smaller commits usally leads to fewer changes per file, making merges easier.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want object files, executable files (result of a build i.e. compiled binaries) and backup files (e.g. `foo.html~`) to be `git` committed.

So you should have a `.gitignore` file and you should set it up as early as possible.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817534/841108)

Once you have a good enough `.gitignore` using `git commit -a -m ....` is sensible. I often do that.

Comment: `git commit -a` doesn't add new files to be tracked by git. Hence no unwanted files like compiled binaries will get pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you have in your working directory.

When you only have sourcecode and other files under version control in there, it won't be a problem. But in many real-world projects, you accumulate various kinds of artifacts in the working directory you don't want to have under version control (especially when they are binary files). Setting up a [.gitignore](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) file which lists any files you don't want under version control can help.

Also, you sometimes work on multiple features simultaneously, but you were a sloppy git user and forgot to create a branch for every feature. In that case you would likely want to commit both features separately. That would mean that you create two commits to which you add the necessary files manually.